# Pumpkin vs Squash

Tags: traducción

If both pumpkin and squash are translated as la calabaza how can you tell the difference in a conversation?  I've looked it up on Spanish Dictionary with no help.

For example: ¿Ya compraste las calabazas para la receta?

Comment: Please bear in mind that not all foods eaten in the States are eaten in other countries. Also, please see my answer. There is no simple answer here.

Comment: You are right: both pumpkin and squash are translated as la calabaza. Here is an example: the Delicata _squash_ is translated to spanish as [Calabaza Delicata](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07NC9RTZC/ref=ox_sc_saved_image_5?smid=A3GQKOQDEQLPRG&psc=1)

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de las plantas cucurbitáceas existe una gran variedad y cuyas característica culinarias no son distinguibles, en este sentido llamamos "**calabacín**" a una variedad de las mismas, habituales en la cocina española. Quizás en inglés pueda corresponderse con el término "summer squash". En español existen numerosos modos para referirse a esta subespecie dentro de las cucurbitáceas ( auyamas, ahuyamas, ayotes, **calabacines**, pipianes, zapallitos, zapallo americano, zapallos,  etc).

En la conversación se diría "**Calabaza (Pumpkin)** y **Calabacín (summer squash)**"

> Within the cucurbitaceous
> plants there is a great variety and whose culinary characteristics are
> not distinguishable, in this sense we call a variety of them
> "**calabacín (zucchini)**", common in Spanish cuisine. Perhaps in
> English it can correspond to the term "summer squash". In Spanish
> there are numerous ways to refer to this subspecies within the
> cucurbits ( auyamas, ahuyamas, ayotes, **calabacines**, pipianes,
> zapallitos, zapallo americano, zapallos,  etc).
>
> In conversation you would say "**Calabaza (Pumpkin)** and **Calabacín (summer squash)**"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_squash

Answer (score 2):

In Chile we don't eat or use "pumpkins", we only see them in advertising related to Halloween. We call this fruit "calabaza" and we don't grow it or eat it or use it for anything.

On the other hand, we do eat different varieties of “squash”, whose name here is "zapallo".

Answer (score 1):

Squash and pumpkin are: Cucurbita
[cucurbita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita)

Click on the Spanish link in the English for this:

> El género Cucurbita, perteneciente a la familia de las cucurbitáceas,
> es un tipo de planta de calabaza originario de América. Se distribuye
> en forma silvestre desde las zonas templado-frescas de los Estados
> Unidos a las de Argentina y Uruguay. Su hábito es de plantas guiadoras
> enredaderas por zarcillos (ausentes en algunos cultivares), rastreras
> y trepadoras. Son sensibles a heladas. **Su pepónide (el fruto de las
> cucurbitáceas) es característicamente una calabaza**. En Cucurbita
> conviven dos grupos ecológicos: las perennes xerofíticas con raíces de
> almacenamiento, y las mesofíticas anuales, entre las que puede haber
> perennes de corta vida que carecen de raíces de almacenamiento

There are TONS of types of squash: Not all eaten in Spanish speaking countries.
Also, there are varieties of squash not eaten so much in Northern Countries

> Cucurbita pepo [aka green squash] is a cultivated plant of the genus
> Cucurbita. It yields varieties of winter squash and pumpkin, but the
> most widespread varieties belong to the subspecies Cucurbita pepo
> subsp. pepo, called summer squash.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gourds_and_squashes)

[cucurbita pepo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_pepo)

**Cada pais tiene sus costumbres. Y el asunto es bastante complicado**.

Aqui está toda la lista con los nombres en latín:

[gourds and squashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gourds_and_squashes)

Diferentes países tendrán diferentes nomes para estas plantas o vegetales.

Voy a hacer un wiki de esta respuesta. Asi las personas en diferentes países pueden decir algo. Por favor, pon los nombres que se utilizan en tu país y describe la planta.